# PHP & Mysql -Queries using symmetric key decryption

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption, encryption-symmetric, adodb-php

I am attempting to use PHP to execute an SQL query which uses symmetric key decryption. However I am unable to get any results.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$sql = "OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ServerKey DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE ServerCertificate WITH PASSWORD = 'P@ssw0rd' SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar, DecryptByKey([address])) AS [address] FROM [serverDBO].[dbo].[allUsers] where id=63";

$result = $db->Execute("$sql");

var_dump($result);
```

The var_dump command results in:

> object(ADORecordSet_empty)#200 (6) { ["dataProvider"]=> string(5)
>   "empty" ["databaseType"]=> bool(false) ["EOF"]=> bool(true)
>   ["_numOfRows"]=> int(0) ["fields"]=> bool(false) ["connection"]=>
>   bool(false) } empty10

- However if I execute the exact same query when connected to the database through Microsoft server management studio I get results returned successfully:

  71 Test Road

Can anyone advise what might be going wrong here or how I can correctly do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

In your `$sql` there is a `SELECT` statement, so you most likely need to fetch the result after executing the statement:

```
$result = $db->execute($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetchRow()) {
  print_r($result);
}
```

See [ADOdb documentation](http://adodb.org/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=v5:userguide:learn_abstraction:using_execute) for more details.

P.S. The double quotes in your `execute()` call simply do nothing, you may omit them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Joachim, I have made the suggested amendments. Unfortunately I still receive no results from this.

Comment: But there should at least be another error message. Maybe it tells what is still wrong

Comment: Using print_r as you have suggested above results in no output at all for me, there are no error messages displayed this way either. 
If I user the var_dump command instead it seems to indicate only that nothing has been returned.